# Difference between ' ' and '\t' in java

Tags: java, string, class, space, difference

```
char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();  
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();  
for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {  
    if ((strArray[i] != ' ') && (strArray[i] != '\t')) {  
        stringBuffer.append(strArray[i]);  
    }  
}  
String noSpaceStr2 = stringBuffer.toString();  
System.out.println(noSpaceStr2);
```

In the above code what is the difference between `(strArray[i] != ' ')`   and `(strArray[i] != '\t')`?

Comment: `' '` is a space (SP) character and `'\t'` is a tab (HT) character.  They are both white-space characters, but the difference is that they are different white-space characters.   And therefore the difference between the tests is that they test for different characters.

Comment: `' '` is what you get when you press the in your keyboard the space. `'\t'` is other separator character: when you press the TAB key, above CAPSLOCK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`' '` is a single space. `'\t'` is a [tab character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters).